# stat() error 'No such file or directory' when file name is returned by readdir()

Tags: c, unix, stat

I'm not able to identify the error thrown by stat. The below program reads all files in a directory and prints the file name:

```
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *dirp;
struct stat sb;

if((dp = opendir(argv[1]))==NULL)
{
    perror("can't open dir");
}
while((dirp = readdir(dp))!=NULL)
{
    if (stat(dirp->d_name, &sb) == -1) {
        perror("stat");
    }   
    printf("File name:               %s \n",dirp->d_name);
}
```

Sample output:

```
/home/eipe
stat error: No such file or directory
File name:               copyofsample 
File name:               a.out 
File name:               . 
stat error: No such file or directory
File name:               udpclient.c 
File name:               .. 
stat error: No such file or directory
File name:               client.c 
stat error: No such file or directory
File name:               ftpclient.c
```

Here are the contents:

```
ls -l /home/eipe/c

-rwxr-xr-x 1 eipe egroup 7751 2011-02-24 15:18 a.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 eipe egroup  798 2011-02-24 13:50 client.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 eipe egroup   15 2011-02-24 15:34 copyofsample
-rw-r--r-- 1 eipe egroup 1795 2011-02-24 15:33 ftpclient.c
-rw-r--r-- 1 eipe egroup  929 2011-02-24 13:34 udpclient.c
```

Comment: Can you print-out the `d_name` for the invalid files? Also, what are all of the files in that directory anyway? Ie, we should see which files are missing.

Comment: i have modified the question. I have print the output of ls command.

Comment: See also [How can I get the list of files in a directory using C or C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612097/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-c).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`dirp->d_name` is the name of the file *in the directory*: for example, `"udpclient.c"`.  The full name of the file is thus `"/home/eipe/c/udpclient.c"` - but your current working directory is `/home/eipe`, so `stat()` is trying to access `"/home/eipe/udpclient.c"`, which doesn't exist.

You can either change your working directory to `argv[1]` using `chdir()`, or you can prepend `argv[1]` to each filename before you call `stat()`.

Answer (score 4):

Note that POSIX 2008 introduces [`fstatat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstatat.html) and related functions (system calls), all distinguished by the `at` suffix to a familiar function name. It also defines [`dirfd()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dirfd.html) to get the file descriptor associated with a directory stream.

The `*at()` functions take one (or two in the case of `renameat()`) open file descriptors that refer to a directory.  This means that another way of coding this, on a system that supports `fstatat()` would be:

```
const char *name = argv[i];

DIR *dp = opendir(dirname);
if (dp == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to open directory %s (%d: %s)\n",
            name, errno, strerror(errno));
    return -1;
}

int dfd = dirfd(dp);    /* Very, very unlikely to fail */

struct dirent *dirp;
while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
{
    struct stat sb;
    if (fstatat(dfd, dirp->d_name, &sb, 0) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fstatat(\"%s/%s\") failed (%d: %s)\n",
                name, dirp->d_name, errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    else
        printf("%-20s %s/%s\n", "File name:", name, dirp->d_name);
}
```

Using `fstatat()` and related functions allows you to use relative pathnames without using [`chdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chdir.html) (which is dangerous; it is hard to get back to where you started without using [`fchdir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchdir.html)), or concatenating names as shown in the [main accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5126055/15168).  For portability, it is probably still advisable to use concatenation anyway — but I was able to test this on Mac OS X (10.10.1) and Linux (Ubuntu 14.04), using the code below.

Developed into a complete program (`test-fstatat.c`):

```
/* SO 0512-5919 */
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700   /* POSIX 2008 plus ... */
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s directory [...]\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        const char *name = argv[i];

        DIR *dp = opendir(name);
        if (dp == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to open directory %s (%d: %s)\n",
                    name, errno, strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }

        int dfd = dirfd(dp);    /* Very, very unlikely to fail */

        printf("%-20s %s\n", "Directory:", name);

        struct dirent *dirp;
        while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
        {
            struct stat sb;
            if (fstatat(dfd, dirp->d_name, &sb, 0) == -1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "fstatat(\"%s/%s\") failed (%d: %s)\n",
                        name, dirp->d_name, errno, strerror(errno));
            }
            else
                printf("%-20s %s/%s\n", "File name:", name, dirp->d_name);
        }

        closedir(dp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ test-fstatat ~/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon
Directory:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/.
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/..
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/mkbod.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/jlssdist.jdc,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/old.msd.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/chksumtool.pl,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/msd2nmd.pl,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/mknmd.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/publictimestamp.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/new.mknmd.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/PRODCODE,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/prodverstamp.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/md5.create.pl,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/jdcrelease.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/JLSS-Dist.mk,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/PRODUCT,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/msd.create.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/distribution.mk,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/nmd.create.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/jlss.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/VERSION,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/cvtjdc.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/redonmd.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/updmsd.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/setnmd.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/list2msd.pl,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/chkmsdnmd.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/vercmp.pl,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/MSD.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/setjdcversion.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/sortnmd.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/gennmd.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/md5.verify.pl,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/setbomversion.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/chkbodlst.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/updnmd.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/domsd.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/md5.chksum.pl,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/bomrelease.pl,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/mkmsd.sh,v
File name:           /Users/jonathanleffler/bin/JLSS-Dist/RCS/fixnmd.sh,v
Directory:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/.
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/..
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/idstest.c
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/idslen
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/install-sh
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/scatterinfo
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/ltmain.sh
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/idsmon.msd
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/idsmon.o
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/configure
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/genscatter
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/config
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/idspacket
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/genconnpacket
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/Makefile
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/config.h.in
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/config.guess
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/depcomp
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/sqlihexdump.o
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/missing
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/install.mk
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/sqlihexdump
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/RCS
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/Makefile.am
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/test.istar.logs.tar.gz
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/idstest.o
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/esqlc.mk
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/config.sub
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/idspacket.o
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/compile
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/Old.Releases
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/esqlc-nosfx.mk
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/osiris_11
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/config.h.in~
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/idstest
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/idsmon.c
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/acr.decode
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/sqlihexdump.dSYM
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/toru.istar
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/dumpdblflt
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/sqlipacket.c
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/toru
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/data.info.tgz
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/idsmon.nmd
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/idsmon.jdc
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/idsmon
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/idsmon.black_19
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/Makefile.in
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/aclocal.m4
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/sqlihexdump.c
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/dumpdblflt.dSYM
File name:           ../../../src/sqltools/idsmon/dumpdblflt.c
$
```

#### POSIX `*at()` functions

The relevant set of functions (other than `dirfd()`) all have names ending `at`, but there are some other POSIX functions that also have names ending `at`.

Relevant:

- [`dirfd()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dirfd.html)
- [`faccessat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/faccessat.html)
- [`fchmodat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchmodat.html)
- [`fchownat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchownat.html)
- [`fstatat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstatat.html)
- [`linkat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/linkat.html)
- [`mkdirat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdirat.html)
- [`mkfifoat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkfifoat.html)
- [`mknodat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mknodat.html)
- [`openat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/openat.html)
- [`readlinkat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readlinkat.html)
- [`renameat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/renameat.html)
- [`symlinkat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/symlinkat.html)
- [`unlinkat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlinkat.html)
- [`utimensat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utimensat.html)

Not directly relevant:

- [`creat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/creat.html)
- [`fstat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstat.html)
- [`lstat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lstat.html)
- [`shmat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmat.html)
- [`stat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html)
- [`strcat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcat.html)
- [`strncat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strncat.html)
- [`wcscat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wcscat.html)
- [`wcsncat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wcsncat.html)

If you plan to process files using file streams (`FILE *`), you need to be aware of:

- [`fdopen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopen.html)