# Readdir() results added to linked list causes seg fault

Tags: c, linux, linked-list

So I'm looping through readdir() function calls and adding the resulting file name to a new node in a linked list. After fixing an issue by setting `file_list = add_file_node()`, I'm running into and issue where the dir_list loop is having problems accessing the directory.

```
hls: cannot access hls: cannot access h: No such file or directory
```

code:

```
#include "header.h"


/**
 * main - main ls function
 *
 * @argc: argument count
 * @argv: argument vector
 *
 * Return: 0, or the errno of the error
 */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct dirent *read;
    char dir[400], error_message[400], format, hidden;
    int i, j, dir_count, max_src_bytes = 397;
    dir_list_t *dir_list, *dir_node;
    file_list_t *file_list;
    DIR *dirp;
    int errno;

    format = ' ';
    hidden = ' ';
    dir_count = 0;

    strcpy(dir, ".");
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (argv[i][0] == '-')
        {
            for (j = 1; argv[i][j]; j++)
            {
                if (argv[i][j] == '1')
                    format = '1';
                else if (argv[i][j] == 'l')
                    format = 'l';
                if (argv[i][j] == 'a')
                    hidden = 'a';
                else if (argv[i][j] == 'A')
                    hidden = 'A';
            }
        }
        else
        {
            memset(dir, 0, strlen(dir));
            strcpy(dir, argv[i]);
            dir_list = add_dir_list(&dir_list, dir);
            dir_count++;
        }
    }

    if (dir_count == 0)
        dir_list = add_dir_list(&dir_list, dir);


    for (dir_node = dir_list; dir_node != NULL; dir_node = dir_node->next)
    {
        dirp = opendir(dir_node->dir);
        if (dirp == NULL)
        {
            strcpy(error_message, "hls: cannot access ");
            max_src_bytes = 381;
            perror(strncat(error_message, dir_node->dir, max_src_bytes));
            return (errno);
        }
        if (dir_count > 1)
            printf("%s:\n", dir_node->dir);


        while ((read = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
        {
            file_list = add_file_list(&file_list, read->d_name);
        }


        switch (format)
        {
            case '1':
                print_ls(hidden, '\n', file_list);
                break;
            case 'l':
                print_ls(hidden, '\n', file_list);
                break;
            default:
                print_ls(hidden, '\t', file_list);
        }
        if (dir_node->next != NULL)
            putchar('\n');

        free_file_list(&file_list);
    }

    free_dir_list(&dir_list);
    closedir(dirp);
    return (0);
}


/**
 * print_ls - print contents in the default ls format, i.e. columns
 *
 * @hidden: parameter denoting the option for revealing hidden files
 * @format: printing format parameter
 * @dirp: pointer to the directory data
 *
 * Return: 0 for success, 1 for failure
 */
int print_ls(char hidden, char format, file_list_t *file_list)
{
    file_list_t *file_node;

    for (file_node = file_list; file_node != NULL; file_node = file_node->next)
    {
        if (hidden == 'a')
        {
            printf("%s", file_list->file);
            if (file_list->next != NULL)
                putchar(format);
        }
        else if (hidden == 'A')
        {
            if (strcmp(file_list->file, ".") != 0 &&
                strcmp(file_list->file, "..") != 0)
            {
                printf("%s", file_list->file);
                if (file_list->next != NULL)
                    putchar(format);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (file_list->file[0] != '.')
            {
                printf("%s", file_list->file); // (line 139)
                if (file_list->next != NULL)
                    putchar(format);
            }
        }
    }
    if (format == '\t')
        printf("\n");

    return (0);
}
```

add_file_list():

```
/**
 * add_file_list - add a new node at the start of a file_list_t linked list
 *
 * @head: start of linked list
 * @file: file data to add to node
 *
 * Return: address of new node; NULL if failure
 */
file_list_t *add_file_list(file_list_t **head, const char file[256])
{
    file_list_t *node;

    node = malloc(sizeof(file_list_t));
    if (node == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    strcpy(node->file, file);
    node->next = *head;
    node->prev = NULL;
    *head = node;
    return (node);
}
```

I'm thinking about trying this out with an array of pointers instead, but I don't want to throw away my code before getting some insight. Am I not inputting the data into the node correctly? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: Dangerous nonsense: `memset(dir, 0, strlen(dir));` And another one: `perror(strncat(error_message, dir_node->dir, max_src_bytes));`

Comment: `append_file_list` prepends.

Comment: `append_file_list` doesn't change `head->prev` (if you want to continue prepending) or `head->next` (if you switch to appending).

Comment: `strcpy(node->file, file);` is dangerous (if `node->file` is a char array) or wrong (if `node->file` is a pointer).

Comment: @wildplasser it fixed an issue I had when printing out multiple directories. If I did `ls test/ my_dir/` It would print out `.my_dir` and `.test/` instead of just `my_dir`.

Comment: I know I have the wrong name, @ikegami. I'm fine with it for now. What would you recommend I do for the char array instead?

Comment: `strncpy` or length check.

Comment: BTW:the code looks *reasonable*, except for the string handling. And: you dont need `()` in `return expression;` return is *not* a function.

Comment: Be aware of how you build pathnames with `readdir()` data — see [`stat()` error ENOENT with `readdir()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125919/).  I've not checked to see if this is part of your problems — the comments suggest you've got other issues to deal with first.  However, look there for advice if your memory management is clean but you still get 'no such file or directory' errors.

Comment: In Linux, and generally on all POSIXy systems, this approach is a dead end. Really. Use [`nftw()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html), [`glob()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html), or [`wordexp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) instead; they are already in your (POSIX) C library.

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong, just as valgrind says

```
   file_head = file_list; <<<< file_list is not initlaized, file_head = junk
    while ((read = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("read: %s\n", read->d_name);
        append_file_list(&file_list, read->d_name);
        printf("file_list: %s\n", file_list->file);
    }
    printf("file_head: %s\n", file_head->file); <<<<<= (line 78) file_head = junk
```

Comment: What should I do to fix that?

Comment: dunno , i dont know what you expect that printf to print. What do you want it to print

Comment: It should print the first file name entry that is added to the linked list

Comment: how about `file_head = append_file_list(....)` inside your loop. That will work because your add function adds at the front and returns the new head

Comment: I tried that, it seems to fix my problem, but now I'm getting `hls: cannot access hls: cannot access h: No such file or directory` as a new error

Comment: Ask a new question. But first - see if you can work it out yourself. Learn to use your debugger

Comment: maybe that message comes from here ` strcpy(error_message, "hls: cannot access ");`

Comment: alright, I'll try to figure this out myself. Thanks @pm100