# C how to find executable files only within given directory?

Tags: c, shell

I'm working on a c programming mimicking UNIX shell and I wonder if there's a way to find an executable file(command file) in a specific directory

Comment: If you are targeting a machine with POSIX extensions, [opendir](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/opendir.html), _ect_ and [fstat](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/fstat.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By executable file, I am assuming you are looking for any file that is not a directory that has the execution flag set.
One way you could go about achieving your goal is to:

1. Get a directory stream corresponding to the directory by using the [opendir](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html).
2. Iterate through the directory stream using  [readdir](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) .
3. At each iteration, find the absolute path of the file, which can be computed by concatenating the directory path and file name (can be obtained by accessing the d_name of the `dirent` struct), pass this path to [stat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lstat.2.html), and use bit mask specified in  [inode documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html)  to check for the execution permission.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> //opendir, stat
#include <dirent.h> //opendir
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> //stat
#include <stdlib.h> //free, malloc

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./a.out path_to_a_directory \n");
        return 1;
    }
    char* path_to_directory = argv[1];
    int path_length = strlen(path_to_directory);
    int modified = 0;
    //Modify path so that a dash is at the end.
    if (path_to_directory[path_length - 1] != '/') {
        char* modified_path = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(path_to_directory) + 2));
        //Copies the null character as well.
        strcpy(modified_path, path_to_directory);
        modified_path[path_length] = '/';
        modified_path[path_length + 1] = '\0';
        path_to_directory = modified_path;
        //Set flag to true so that the dynamically allocated memory is freed later.
        modified = 1;
    }

    //Get the directory stream corresponding to the directory. 
    DIR* in_directory_stream = opendir(path_to_directory);
    if (in_directory_stream == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: the specified directory cannot be found or opened. \n", errno);
        if (modified) free(path_to_directory);
        return 1;
    }
    dirent* entry = NULL; 
    printf("Files that are executable by at least one of the permission classes (owner, group, others) are: \n");
    while ((entry = readdir(in_directory_stream)) != NULL) {
        //All directories contain . and .., which corresponds to current and parent directory respectively,
        //in unix systems. Since we are looking for only executable files, we can ignore them. 
        if (!strcmp(".", entry->d_name)) {
            continue;
        }
        if (!strcmp("..", entry->d_name)) {
            continue;
        }
        //Get file information. 
        struct stat entry_info;
        /* Create the absolute path of the entry.
         * Without it, as mentioned by Shawn below, 
         * stat will look for a file with the entry's name in current working directory 
         * instead of the specified directory. 
         */
        char* entry_absolute_path  = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(path_to_directory) 
                    + strlen(entry->d_name) + 1));
        strcat(entry_absolute_path, path_to_directory);
        strcat(entry_absolute_path, entry->d_name);       
       if (stat(entry_absolute_path, &entry_info) == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in obtaining file information about %s\n", entry->d_name);
       } else {
           // Check if the file is not a directory and 
           // is executable by one of the permission classes (owner, group, others). 
           if (((entry_info.st_mode & S_IFMT) != S_IFDIR) && 
                   ((entry_info.st_mode & S_IXUSR) || (entry_info.st_mode & S_IXGRP) 
                   || (entry_info.st_mode & S_IXOTH))) {
               printf("%s\n", entry->d_name);
           }
       } 
           free(entry_absolute_path);
    }
    //Close directory stream.
    closedir(in_directory_stream);    
    if (modified) free(path_to_directory);
    return 0;


}
```

EDIT: Corrected the program to pass the absolute path of the file to `stat`. Prior to this edit, the stat was given only the file name resulting in the program searching only the current working directory. Error identified by [Shawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9952196/shawn)

Comment: Gotta take into account the filename in the `dirent` struct doesn't include directory. Need that too for `stat()`.

Comment: What do you mean by the "file name in the `dirent` struct doesn't include directory "? My understanding is that if a directory contained a subdirectory, we would get a `dirent` struct corresponding to that subdirectory when we iterate through the directory stream.

Comment: If you `opendir()` "/foo/bar/", the file names don't have `/foo/bar/` in front, so unless you're scanning your current working directory, `stat()` will fail unless a file with the same name just happens to be present in the cwd - and it'll be looking at the wrong file in that case.

Comment: See [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125919/stat-error-no-such-file-or-directory-when-file-name-is-returned-by-readdir) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for identifying that error. I have corrected the program above.