# Directories being found but not being recognized as directories

Tags: c, windows, directory

I am using the stat.h header and stat() to read and list files and directories in a directory. I've tried my code with different preset directories to see the result and print the corresponding type of the entry and so far in each test the code shows the current directory and 2 sub directories as directories but shows the other directories as files despite having the correct path listed alongside it

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 #include <dirent.h>

 #include <locale.h>

 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <wchar.h>



       extern int errno;
       int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
         setlocale(LC_ALL,"Turkish");
         DIR* dp;
         struct dirent dirp;
         char test[9999];
         

         getcwd(test,9999);
         printf("FOLDERMAIN:%s\n",test);
         dp=opendir(".");
         searchDirectoryForString(dp,"Mat",test);
      
      
         return 0;
 }


void searchDirectoryForString(DIR* dp,char* str,char* directoryname)
     {

        int lineno=1,num=0;
        FILE* fp;
        struct dirent *file;
        char temp[99999];
        char buf[99999];
        char *rpath;
        rpath = calloc(99999,1);
        char path[99999];
        char* temppath;
        temppath = calloc(99999,1);
        int count = 0;
        char dirhold[100];
        char* dot;
        int line_num = 1;
        int find_result=0;
        static int check=0;

        DIR* fdp;
        if(dp==NULL)
         {
         printf("cant open");
         }
         struct stat filestat;



while (file=readdir(dp)) {
      stat(file->d_name,&filestat);
       //printf("%s\n",file->d_name);
       if(strcmp(file->d_name,"..")==0||(strcmp(file->d_name,".")==0))
       continue;
          if ( S_ISDIR(filestat.st_mode))
          {
            check++;
            printf("\n CHECK: %d\n",check);
            if(check!=1)
            {
                strcpy(temppath,directoryname);
                printf("temp:%s\n",directoryname);
                strcat(directoryname,"\\");
                strcat(directoryname,file->d_name);
                dot = strrchr(directoryname, '\\');
                strcpy(dirhold,dot);
                printf("DIR: %s\n",dirhold);
                printf("%s KLASÖR\n",directoryname);
                chdir(directoryname);
                dp=opendir(directoryname);
                if(dp==NULL)
                {
                    printf("2\n");
                }
                strcat(temppath,dirhold);
                searchDirectoryForString(dp,str,temppath);
            }
            else{
            strcpy(path,directoryname);
            strcat(directoryname,"\\");
            strcat(directoryname,file->d_name);
            dot = strrchr(directoryname, '\\');
            strcpy(dirhold,dot);
            printf("DIR: %s\n",dirhold);
            printf("%s FOLDER\n",directoryname);
            chdir(directoryname);
            dp=opendir(directoryname);
            if(dp==NULL)
            {
            printf("2\n");
            }
            strcat(path,dirhold);
            searchDirectoryForString(dp,str,path);
          }
          }
          else
          {
                snprintf(buf,99999,"%s",directoryname);
                strcat(buf,"\\");
                //strcat(directoryname,dirhold);
                strcat(buf,file->d_name);
                printf("%s FILE \n",buf);
         


//Close the file if still open.
if(fp) {
    fclose(fp);
    strcpy(rpath," ");
}


        }
    } 
   }


}
```

I tried my best to produce an MCVE below. One new thing i noticed is if i add another folder to a preset folder it is not recognized as a folder. If i add a folder to a folder which is one of the recognized folders it is also recognized as a folder(nested folder) the issue is most likely caused by the stat function so wrote another function for it to be able to seen more clearly as its in its own scope. Im using devc++ as my IDE.

```
    #include <locale.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <dirent.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <wchar.h>


    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
      setlocale(LC_ALL,"Turkish");
      DIR* dp;
      struct dirent dirp;
      char test[9999];
      getcwd(test,9999);
      printf("FOLDERMAIN:%s\n",test);
      dp=opendir(".");
      listDir(dp,test);
      
      
  return 0;
   }
       int isDir(const char *name) {
             struct stat fileStat;
              return !stat(name, &fileStat) && S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode);
       }

   void listDir(DIR* dp,char* directoryname)
     {
        struct dirent *file;
        char buf[99999];
        char* temppath;
        temppath = calloc(99999,1);
        int count = 0;
        char dirhold[100];
        char* dot;
        int line_num = 1;
        int find_result=0;
        static int check=0;
        char* dir;
        DIR* fdp;
        if(dp==NULL)
         {
         printf("cant open");
         }
        while (file=readdir(dp)) {
       //printf("%s\n",file->d_name);
       if(strcmp(file->d_name,"..")==0||(strcmp(file->d_name,".")==0))
       continue;
          if (isDir(file->d_name))
          {
            check++;
            printf("\n CHECK: %d\n",check);
        
                
                strcpy(temppath,directoryname);
                printf("temp:%s\n",directoryname);
                strcat(directoryname,"\\");
                strcat(directoryname,file->d_name);
                dot = strrchr(directoryname, '\\');
                strcpy(dirhold,dot);
                printf("DIR: %s\n",dirhold);
                printf("%s FOLDER\n",directoryname);
                chdir(directoryname);
                dp=opendir(directoryname);
                if(dp==NULL)
                {
                    printf("2\n");
                }
                
                strcat(temppath,dirhold);
                listDir(dp,temppath);
          }
          else
          {
                snprintf(buf,99999,"%s",directoryname);
                strcat(buf,"\\");
                strcat(buf,file->d_name);
                printf("%s FILE\n",buf);
          }
 }
 }
```

Comment: If you were coding on Unix (POSIX) systems, it would be an odds-on bet that the problem and the fixes are described in [`stat()` error "no such file or directory when file name is returned by `readdir()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125919/stat-error-no-such-file-or-directory-when-file-name-is-returned-by-readdir).  Even on Windows, you are likely to be running into similar problems.  However, there are Windows-specific APIs to process directories that could be used instead of `readdir()` et al.  And there is a lot of code (and commented out code) which could have problems.

Comment: Note that using `chdir()` is error prone — doubly so if there are symlinks lurking around — and should be avoided when possible.  You have a large number of occurrences of `99999`; there should be a macro for that value.  On Unix systems, you must `#include <errno.h>` and should never define `extern int errno;` because `errno` is typically not a simple variable but rather an expression that evaluates to a per-thread `int` value.  I think the same is true on Windows.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  With the commented out code, yours is not an MCVE.  If that was removed, it might be OK.

Comment: I have added a mcve now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my code that does more or less what you want.  It is also available  in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as file `dirlist43.c` in the [src/so-7406-2431](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/so-7406-2431) sub-directory.

#### What went wrong in the MCVE code?

There were a fairly large number of problems, including:

- Not much error checking for failed calls.
- Changing directory with changing back correctly.
- No debug code to help determine what is going wrong.
- Too many places where `opendir()` was called.
- Too many places where the result of `opendir()` was checked — one of them in a different function from where the call was made.
- Missing headers.
- Unused variables.
- Not reporting errors on `stderr`.
- Confusion about `directoryname` vs `temppath`.
- **Sequencing of `chdir()` calls worked downwards, once.** But there was no code to change back after finishing a directory.
- **Missing `closedir()`** — I ran out of file descriptors when run on a directory with about 3000 sub-folders.
- *More debatable:* I've used `snprintf()` or `printf()` to concatenate strings.  For raw performance, you may find that `strcpy()` and `strcat()` are quicker, but using `strcat()` can slow things down as it scans from the start of the string each time.  Clever code determines the length of the string so that you can copy each time you append, but the Standard C functions aren't helpful for that.

And notes from another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74062431/directories-being-found-but-not-being-recognized-as-directories/74074171#comment130766788_74062431):

- Note that using `chdir()` is error prone — doubly so if there are symlinks lurking around — and should be avoided when possible.  *(This was an accurate comment.)*
- You have a large number of occurrences of 99999 (and some occurrences of 9999); there should be a macro (or enumeration constant) for that value.
- On Unix systems, you must `#include <errno.h>` and should never declare `extern int errno;` because `errno` is typically not a simple variable but rather an expression that evaluates to a per-thread `int` value. I think the same is true on Windows.

#### Other solutions

In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74062431/directories-being-found-but-not-being-recognized-as-directories#comment130766760_74062431), I noted that:

> If you were coding on a Unix (POSIX) system, it would be an odds-on bet that the problem and the fixes are described in [`stat()` error "no such file or directory when file name is returned by `readdir()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5125919/15168). Even on Windows, you are likely to be running into similar problems. However, there are Windows-specific APIs to process directories that could be used instead of `readdir()`.

Since your MCVE code uses Windows-style `\` path separators but compiles, the majority of the advice in that question is valid.  Note that POSIX provides some functions — [`fstatat()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fstatat.html) and [`dirfd()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dirfd.html) — that avoid messing around with `chdir()`.  This is advantageous, especially in threaded programs as `chdir()` changes directory for all threads at the same time, which is apt to cause chaos if the different threads are accessing files in different directories identified by relative rather than absolute pathnames.

#### Code: `dirlist43.c`

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifdef UNIX
#define DIRSEP_STR  "/"
#define DIRSEP_CHR  '/'
#else
#define DIRSEP_STR  "\\"
#define DIRSEP_CHR  '\\'
#endif

#define PATH_LEN    99999

extern void listDir(const char *directoryname);
extern int isDir(const char *name);

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
    char pwd[PATH_LEN];
    getcwd(pwd, sizeof(pwd));
    printf("FOLDERMAIN: %s\n", pwd);
    listDir(pwd);
    return 0;
}

int isDir(const char *name)
{
    struct stat fileStat;
    int rc = stat(name, &fileStat) == 0 && S_ISDIR(fileStat.st_mode);
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("%s(): %d [%s]\n", __func__, rc, name);
#endif /* DEBUG */
    return rc;
}

#ifdef DEBUG
static void chk_pwd(const char *tag)
{
    char pwd[PATH_LEN];
    if (getcwd(pwd, sizeof(pwd)) == 0)
    {
        int errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "%s(): getcwd() failed: %d %s\n",
                __func__, errnum, strerror(errnum));
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("PWD: %s [%s]\n", tag, pwd);
}
#else
#define chk_pwd(tag)    ((void)0)
#endif /* DEBUG */

static void set_pwd(const char *directoryname)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("CHDIR 1: [%s]\n", directoryname);
#endif /* DEBUG */
    if (chdir(directoryname) != 0)
    {
        int errnum = errno;
        fprintf(stderr, "%s(): chdir(%s) failed: %d %s\n",
                __func__, directoryname, errnum, strerror(errnum));
        exit(1);
    }
    chk_pwd("CHDIR 1");
}

void listDir(const char *directoryname)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
    static int level = 0;
#endif /* DEBUG */
    static int check = 0;

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("-->> %s() level %d (%s)\n", __func__, ++level, directoryname);
#endif /* DEBUG */

    DIR *dp = opendir(directoryname);
    if (dp == NULL)
    {
        perror(directoryname);
        return;
    }

    set_pwd(directoryname);

    struct dirent *file;
    while ((file = readdir(dp)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(file->d_name, "..") == 0 || (strcmp(file->d_name, ".") == 0))
            continue;
        if (isDir(file->d_name))
        {
            printf("CHECK: %d\n", ++check);
            char temppath[PATH_LEN];
            snprintf(temppath, sizeof(temppath), "%s%s%s",
                     directoryname, DIRSEP_STR, file->d_name);
            printf("FOLDER: %s\n", temppath);
            chk_pwd("Before recursion");
            listDir(temppath);
            set_pwd(directoryname);
            chk_pwd("After recursion");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("FILE: %s%s%s\n", directoryname, DIRSEP_STR, file->d_name);
        }
    }
    closedir(dp);

#ifdef DEBUG
    printf("<<-- %s() level %d (%s)\n", __func__, level--, directoryname);
#endif /* DEBUG */
}
```

It can be compiled with `-DUNIX` if you work on a POSIX-like system where slash `/` is used to separate path components, or without if you work on a Windows-like system where backslash `\` is used.  It can be compiled with `-DDEBUG` to get copious extra debugging output.

The `makefile` is configured for Unix — the code was tested on a MacBook Pro running macOS Big Sur 11.7.