# Calculating size of Directory in C

Tags: c

I want to calculate the size of the directory (path) recursively. In my current code I have a function that identifies if it's a directory or file, if it's a directory it calls the function with the subdirectory (file) and if it's a file it adds to the totalSize variable. However, my current code doesn't return anything meaning that there is an error somewhere.
here is my code -

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void getsize(const char *path,int* totalSize);

int main()
{
    int total = 0;
    char path [] = "C:\\Users\\abbas\\Desktop\\Leetcode airplane";
    getsize(path,&total);
    printf("%d",total);
    return total;

}


void getsize(const char *path,int* totalSize)
{
    struct dirent *pDirent;
    struct stat buf;
    struct stat info;
    DIR *pDir;
    int exists;
    char str[100];
    pDir = opendir (path);
    while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
    {
        stat(pDirent->d_name,&info);
        if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
        {
            strcpy(str,path);
            strcat(str,"/");
            strcat(str,pDirent->d_name);
            getsize(str,totalSize);
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(str,path);
            strcat(str,"/");
            strcat(str,pDirent->d_name);
            exists = stat(str,&buf);
            if (exists < 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                (*totalSize) += buf.st_size;
            }

        }
    }
    closedir(pDir);
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d\n", total);` ?

Comment: As an aside, your `main` should return `0`, not the total, which will be taken as an error indication.  `0` means success, non-zero means error.  Also, add a newline to the end of the print format.  Never just terminate your strings mid-line with no newline.

Comment: You need to include string.h, and that fixed size str[100] is problematic.

Comment: I'd be surprised indeed if you're not running into the problem described in [`stat()` error "no such file or directory" when file name is returned by `readdir()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125919/stat-error-no-such-file-or-directory-when-file-name-is-returned-by-readdir)

Comment: I am getting a "free(): invalid pointer" on infinitely recursion on /<path>/../<path>.

Answer (score 5):

1. Include string.h.
2. The arbitrary fixed size`str[100]` is problematic.  If you are on Linux include linux/limits.h and use `str[PATH_MAX]` or even better `pathconf(path, _PC_NAME_MAX)`.  In either case you should either ensure the buffer is big enough (using `snprintf()` for instance), or dynamically allocate the buffer.
3. You need to exclude `.` and `..` otherwise you end up with an infinite loop (`path/../path/..`).
4. `stat(pDirent->d_name,&info)` fails as you need to `stat()` `path`/`pDirect->d_name` not just `pDirect->d_name`.
5. (not fixed) Maybe `snprintf(path2, sizeof path2, "%s%s%s", path, PATH_SEP, pDirenv->d_name)` instead of `strcpy()` and `strcat()`?
6. Check return values of functions otherwise you are wasting time.
7. No point of doing two `stat()` calls on the same path so just use `(*totalSize) += buf.st_size;`.
8. (not fixed) On Windows, consider using _stat64() with the address of a struct __stat64 (@AndrewHenle).
9. I assume you only want the size of files.
10. (not fixed) It would be more natural if `getsize()` returned the size instead of using `int *totalSize` out parameter.
11. (not fixed) Consider using `nftw()` (or the older `ftw()`) to walk the tree.

Note that program now accept path via command line for testing purposes.

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

const char PATH_SEP =
#ifdef _WIN32
    "\\";
#else
     "/";
#endif

void getsize(const char *path,int *totalSize) {
    struct dirent *pDirent;
    DIR *pDir = opendir (path);
    while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL) {
        if(
            !strcmp(pDirent->d_name, ".") ||
            !strcmp(pDirent->d_name, "..")
        )
            continue;

        char path2[PATH_MAX];
        strcpy(path2, path);
        strcat(path2, PATH_SEP);
        strcat(path2, pDirent->d_name);
        struct stat info;
        if(stat(path2, &info) == -1) {
            perror("stat");
            return;
        }
        if(S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
            getsize(path2, totalSize);
        else if(S_ISREG(info.st_mode))
            (*totalSize) += info.st_size;
    }
    closedir(pDir);
}

int main(argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: your_program path\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int total = 0;
    getsize(argv[1], &total);
    printf("%d\n",total);
}
```

and example test:

```
$ mkdir -p 1/2
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=1/file count=123
123+0 records in
123+0 records out
62976 bytes (63 kB, 62 KiB) copied, 0.000336838 s, 187 MB/s
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=1/2/file count=234
234+0 records in
234+0 records out
119808 bytes (120 kB, 117 KiB) copied, 0.0015842 s, 75.6 MB/s
$ echo $((62976 + 119808))
182784
$ ./your_program 1
182784
```

Comment: May be worth a mention, if all that is wanted is a total, POSIX `nftw()` (or `ftw()`) will walk the entire directory subtree allowing for the total calculation -- while taking advantage of the efficiency and error checks those functions provide.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks.  I added a note as suggested.

Comment: Lots of good advise in the answer. If I could vote twice I would.

Comment: Minor points: if by "total size", OP means "disk space used", `(*totalSize) += info.st_size;` does not account for sparse files using less disk space than the size of the file would otherwise indicate; and using an automatic variable for `path2` could cause issues for deep directory trees; and really pedantic:  `PATH_MAX` won't be defined on systems that have different path limits on different filesystem implementations and that strictly adhere to POSIX specifications.  In that case `[f]pathconf(_PC_NAME_MAX)` should be used to get the max name length for that particular file system.

Comment: And [Windows `stat()` isn't quite so simple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=msvc-170), with 6 different `stat()` implementations for various 32/64 bit combinations of values (12 counting wide characters).  On Windows, it's probably best to use `_stat64()` with the address of a `struct __stat64` passed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks.  I don't use Windows so I don't have a way of testing the latter suggestion but I will note it above.  What is your concern re path2 and deep directory trees?

Comment: @AllanWind `PATH_MAX` is usually something like 4096 - large enough that recursion in deep directory trees could cause stack overflow, especially for multithreaded processes where a thread's stack might be both smaller than the main thread's stack and unable to grow. Stack overflow isn't really much of a problem for single-threaded 64-bit processes on current systems with GBs of RAM. The second is that `PATH_MAX` really isn't the max path length possible.  See [POSIX `pathconf()` **RATIONALE**](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/pathconf.html#tag_16_157_08).

Comment: (cont) "The value returned for the variable {PATH_MAX} indicates the longest **relative** pathname that could be given if the specified directory is the current working directory of the process."

Answer (score 3):

I think the major error of your code lies in the recursive logic.

To quote pp.183 of *The C Programming Language*:

> Each directory always contains entries for itself, called ".",
> and its parent, ".."; these must be skipped, or the program will
> loop forever.

Therefore, maybe you can try adding the following `if` test
at the beginning of the `while` loop:

```
while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
{
    if (strcmp(pDirent->d_name, ".") == 0
        || strcmp(pDirent->d_name, "..") == 0)
        continue;  /* skip self and parent */
    /* ... */
}
```

Still, there might be other errors, but I think this one is the most significant.

Answer (score 1):

**Practice safe coding.**

Below risks buffer overflow.

```
        // Risky
        strcpy(str,path);
        strcat(str,"/");
        strcat(str,pDirent->d_name);
```

Had code done,

```
int len = snprintf(str, sizeof str, "%s/%s", path, pDirent->d_name);
if (len < 0 || (unsigned) len >= sizeof str) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Path too long %s/%s\n", path, pDirent->d_name);
  exit (-1);  
}
```

Then the code would have readily errored out do to recursion on `"."` and `".."` and **led to OP's self-discovery** of a key problem.

This make for faster code production and more resilient code.  Saves OP time.